# using GridFS with Tornado templates

Tags: tornado, pymongo, gridfs

i've a problem when making a loop using a GridFS pictures:

```
class VentesHandler(BaseHandler): 
    @tornado.web.authenticated 
    def get(self): 
        user = self.get_secure_cookie("mechtari") 
        info = tornado.escape.json_decode(user) 
        email = info["personnel"]["email"] 
        produits = self.db.users.find({"personnel.email":email},{"produit_up":1, "_id":0}).distinct("produit_up") 
        produit_pic_id = self.db.users.find({"personnel.email":email}).distinct("produit_up.avatar.photo") 
        orientation = self.db.users.find({"personnel.email":email}).distinct("produit_up.avatar.orientation") 
        renderer = self.fs 
        self.render("ventes.html", produits=produits, produit_pic_id=produit_pic_id, orientation=orientation, renderer=renderer)
```

and the template:

```
{% for produit in produits %} 
{% for id in produit_pic_id %} 
<div class="produit"> 
{% import pymongo %} 
{% if orientation=="portrait" %} <!-- dumb technic to avoid image stretching ^_^ --> 
<span><img src="/{{renderer.get(pymongo.son_manipulator.ObjectId([id for id in produit_pic_id])).filename}}" height="200px" class="imag"> 
 {% else %} 
 <span><img src="/{{renderer.get(pymongo.son_manipulator.ObjectId(id)).filename}}" width="200px"class="imag"> 
 {% end %} 
 </div> 
 </div> 
{% end %} 
{% end %} 
{% end %}
```

i got the pictures repeated the time of uploaded products! so if i 
uploaded 2 products (product_up), then i'll get 4 products with all 
possibles switching of the product pictures! 
by the way, note the hack to avoid (self not defined...) 
and what about the import? do i make another variable

```
x = pymongo.son_manipulator
```

to avoid the template to load the whole module 
and uses a lot of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, there was a loop in a loop.
[Answer on Google groups](https://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/6382bcfa028d547)

here is the code:

```
class VentesHandler(BaseHandler): 
    @tornado.web.authenticated 
    def get(self): 
        user = self.get_secure_cookie("mechtari") 
        info = tornado.escape.json_decode(user) 
        email = info["personnel"]["email"] 
        try: 
            produits = self.db.users.find({"personnel.email":email}, {"produit_up":1, "_id":0}).distinct("produit_up") 
            renderer = self.fs 
        except (errors.AutoReconnect, errors.ConnectionFailure): 
            self.redirect("/error") 
    self.render("ventes.html", produits=produits, renderer=renderer)
```

the template:

```
{% for produit in produits %} 
<div class="produit"> 
{% from bson import ObjectId %} 
{% if produit["avatar"]["orientation"]=="portrait" %} 
<span><img src="/{{renderer.get(ObjectId(produit["avatar"] ["photo"])).filename}}" height="300px" class="imag"> 
{% else %} 
<span><img src="/{{renderer.get(ObjectId(produit["avatar"] ["photo"])).filename}}"width="300px"class="imag">
{% end %} 
</div> 
{% end %}
```